# How to integrate a thid party form with parameters in my Rails application?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I need to integrate a registering form from Insightly CRM in my RoR 4.2 application. Generating and copying the form works fine. I tried 2 ways of doing it:

1. within the Rails framework, setting up the route pointing to the register.html.erb file
2. beside the framework, storing the register.html file in the public folder

Here is the form as defined in the register.htmlfile:

```
    <form name="insightly_web_to_contact" action="https://3dpm22c7.insight.ly/WebToContact/Create" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="formId" value="2prk0LYdnS7meZcIkHGrYg=="/>
      <label for="insightly_firstName">First Name: </label>
      <input id="insightly_firstName" name="FirstName" type="text"/>
      ...
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Now I want to pass parameters to the form to pre-fill some fields. So I write the URL: `http://localhost:3000/register?FirstName=FRED`

But it does not initialise the variable of the input field :

Is it possible to do it within the framework?

What would be the syntax to have it working?

Thanks for helping.

Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set variables in your controller so that you aren't worrying about params in your view since that is not it's job. You can set instance variables in your controller action and then set the value using erb like:

```
class YouController < MyApp::ApplicationController
  def index
    @first_name = params['FirstName']
    #So on
  end
end
```

`<input id="insightly_firstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="<%= @first_name %>" />`

You could optionally also use the rails form helper to build your form as well, although that doesn't really matter for this code I suppose.